# Custom method in an Angular service using $resource in Jhipster

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, angularjs-resource

I don't understand the syntax to write a custom method in an Angular Service using $resource in Jhipster. After a lot of research, I am doubtful whether it's even possible.

Here is the code for Angular Service.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('tealboxApp')
        .factory('Task', Task);
Task.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];

function Task ($resource, DateUtils) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/tasks/:id';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    data.assignedDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.assignedDateTime);
                    data.startDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.startDateTime);
                    data.endDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.endDateTime);
                    data.startDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.startDate);
                    data.endDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.endDate);
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT',
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var copy = angular.copy(data);
                copy.startDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.startDate);
                copy.endDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.endDate);
                return angular.toJson(copy);
            }
        },
        'save': {
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var copy = angular.copy(data);
                copy.startDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.startDate);
                copy.endDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.endDate);
                return angular.toJson(copy);
            }
        }
    });
}
})();
```

I want to add a custom method like...

```
'getTasksWithXYZ': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    data.assignedDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.assignedDateTime);
                    data.startDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.startDateTime);
                    data.endDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.endDateTime);
                    data.startDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.startDate);
                    data.endDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.endDate);
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
```

I am not sure how to pass a parameter to this get method or even how to call this method in the controller.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your service add `params`

```
    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {


     'getTasksWithXYZ': {
        method: 'GET',
        params:{id:'@id'},
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                data.assignedDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.assignedDateTime);
                data.startDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.startDateTime);
                data.endDateTime = DateUtils.convertDateTimeFromServer(data.endDateTime);
                data.startDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.startDate);
                data.endDate = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.endDate);
            }
            return data;
        }
    }

     })
```

In your controller `Task.getTasksWithXYZ(id)`

Comment: But how can I specify a different url, if you understand spring rest then this is my code on the spring controller which I need to call.



   ` /**
     * GET  /tasks : get all the tasks assigned to User
     *
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of tasks in body
     */
    @GetMapping("/tasks/assignedByUser")
    @Timed
    public List<Task> getAllTasksAssignedByUser(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Tasks");
        return taskService.findAllAssignedByUser(userId);
    } `

Comment: I am sorry the code in the comment is not getting rendered properly, I am missing something